# Package Manager Console init file in VS2013

Tags: powershell-2.0, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to find the startup script for the Package Manager Console, the one that loads all the NuGet and Entity Framework cmdlets.

I found:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\NuGet Packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\tools\init.ps1
```

and

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\NuGet Packages\EntityFramework.6.0.0\tools\init.ps1
```

but I'm not sure they are run.  (I added some Write-Host calls, but the text doesn't appear.)

Any ideas?  I'd like to call my regular PS startup script to get all my aliases, as well as posh-git, hooked up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path may differ, but I was able to locate the NuGet Profile.ps1 for VS2013 at the following path on my machine:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\42pikggq.plv\Modules\NuGet\Profile.ps1**

I did not modify it since it's signed and I'm in the middle of my workday (don't want to start mucking about with things that might leave me unable to work.)

Let me know if this is the appropriate file, I'm interested in knowing as well since I have a few functions I would like to import into VS2013 for working with AWS.

Comment: Thanks, my path was slightly different, but the Profile.ps1 is what I was looking for; I can run my preferred startup script from there.
Is there a way to find out, in Profile.ps1, what file called it?  Something executes after Profile.ps1...

Comment: Not sure, no, there is the NuGet.psd1 which sits at the same location and specifies Profile.ps1 as the only script to be executed, if other scripts are executed it may be done by the PS host itself (rather than from another script.)  You may find this info helpful, though: http://poshoholic.com/2008/03/18/powershell-deep-dive-using-myinvocation-and-invoke-expression-to-support-dot-sourcing-and-direct-invocation-in-shared-powershell-scripts/

Comment: Specifically the section discussing "$MyInvocation.InvocationName" about half-way into the article.

Comment: Thanks, Shaun.  "Write-Host $MyInvocation.InvocationName"  emits nothing.

Answer (score 1):

This file will be executed automatically:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\NuGet_profile.ps1
```

... Without the need to change anything in signed ps files.

Read more here:
https://docs.nuget.org/consume/Setting-up-NuGet-PowerShell-Profile.md